# Deciding if the largest absolute value real root lies in a cyclotomic extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Given an algebraic equation of degree $n$ of form: $$x^{n} - a_{n-1}x^{n-1} - a_{n-2}x^{n-2} - \dots - a_{0} = 0$$ where each $a_{i} \in \Bbb Q^{+}$ and atleast one positive root, how does one decide efficiently if the largest magnitude positive root lies in a cyclotomic extension?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139328/how-to-test-if-a-root-of-a-polynomial-is-cyclotomic-and-find-a-cyclotomic-formul for some discussion about the suitability of this question.

Comment: Above link will be dead now, see http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1624/testing-whether-algebraic-numbers-are-cyclotomic-discussion-record/ if you care.

Comment: The link isn't dead (now), not if one has enough points. But the tea site, I thought that was just an archive for the old meta site, not for new stuff, now that we have a meta site as part of SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Factoring polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ is easy both in theory and practice so you might as well assume that you know the minimal polynomial of the root.

(2) Let $r$ be the largest real root. The assumption that your polynomial is of the minimal form implies that all the other roots have magnitude $\leq r$ (as I assume you realize). <strike>Conversely, if $r$ is a positive real algebraic number all of whose Galois conjugtes have norm $<r$, then it obeys a polynomial of this form.</strike>  Crossed out claim is false; $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a counterexample. Draw a picture of the points $((2+\sqrt{3})^n, (2-\sqrt{3})^n)$ to see why.

(3) Suppose that $f(x)$ is irreducible with integer coefficients. Let $p$ be a prime not dividing the discriminant of $f$ and let $f(x) = \prod g_i(x)$ be the factorization of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$. If the roots of $f$ lie in a cyclotomic field, then all the $g_i$ have the same degree. (This follows from the using relation between factoring polynomials modulo primes and the Galois group; see for example [here](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/08/24/factoring-polynomials-and-the-frobenius/), or Chapter 2 in Villegas' *Experimental Number Theory*, as suggested by Felipe Voloch.) This gives a rapid way to prove that the roots of a polynomial are NOT cyclotomic.

Unfortunately, the converse doesn't hold: The above criterion will be true whenever the splitting field of $f$ is generated by a single root of $f$. **I suspect there are clever ways to use reduction modulo primes to rapidly reject more $f$'s.**

(4) From basic class field theory, the roots of $f$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i/N})$ if and only if the factorization of $f$ modulo $p$ is determined by the value of $p$ modulo $N$. Also, all the primes dividing such an $N$ will occur in the discriminant of $f$. I suspect that this is a good way to guess $N$ in practice.

(5) See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36536) for the question of how to find $N$ if we are promised that some such $N$ exists. In particular, the methods there will give you an $N$ which will work if any $N$ works so, by [Trager's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_over_algebraic_extensions_.28Trager.27s_method.29), the problem is computable. **I do not know what the best method is in practice.**

(6) See theorem 1.0.5 of [Calegari-Morrison-Snyder](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0665) for a complete classification when the $a_i$ are integers and the largest root is less than $76/33 \approx 2.303$. I believe that Morrison and Snyder (both of whom are very active on MO) have since published stronger results.

Comment: Could you elaborate 'if the factorization of f modulo p is determined by the value of p modulo N'?

Comment: To all but finitely many primes $p$, there is a conjugacy class $Frob(p)$ in the Galois group. This conjugacy class determines the factorization of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. If $f$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i/N})$, then $\mathrm{Frob}(p)$ is determined by $p \bmod N$. E.g. $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i/5})$. By quadratic reciprocity, the polynomial $x^2-5$ factors mod $p$ if $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 5$ and not if $p \equiv \pm 2 \bmod 5$. See a good book on algebraic number theory.

Comment: For (3) see Villegas's book "Experimental Number Theory" section 2.5